# EhCache 3.1.3 persistence issue

Tags: java, persistence, ehcache, disk

I'm having issues with persistence in ehcache. The cache itself works fine when first started but it does not remember the old values when I restart my tomcat servlet. 
Here's my code for initializing ehcache. I'm not using any xml.

```
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.PersistentCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.Status;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;

PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager =
    CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
            .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence("/cache"))
            .withCache("test-cache",
                    CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                            Integer.class, String.class,
                            ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                    .heap(1, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                                    .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB)
                                    .disk(20, MemoryUnit.MB)
                    )
            ).build(true);
Cache cache = persistentCacheManager.getCache("test-cache", Integer.class, String.class);

log.info("Cache get 1 before putting: " + cache.get(1));
for(int i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    cache.put(i,"Hello");
}
log.info("Cache get 1 after putting: " + cache.get(1));
```

Result of the "before" log statement is always null after a restart.

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand what "persistence" means in this context? I thought the whole point was to keep the cache saved on the disk so it can be reloaded during server restarts.

Comment: The docs suggest you are correct, but I have no idea what you're missing. Be patient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your disk ressource pool as persistent. It is not by default.

```
.disk(20, MemoryUnit.MB, true)
```

Then your test works perfectly.

The complete code including closing the cache manager:

```
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.PersistentCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder.*;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.*;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder.*;

public class Main {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager =
        newCacheManagerBuilder()
            .with(persistence("cache"))
            .withCache("test-cache",
                newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                    Integer.class, String.class,
                    newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                        .heap(1, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                        .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB)
                        .disk(20, MemoryUnit.MB, true)
                )
            ).build(true)) {
      Cache cache = persistentCacheManager.getCache("test-cache", Integer.class, String.class);

      log.info("Cache get 1 before putting: " + cache.get(1));
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cache.put(i, "Hello");
      }
      log.info("Cache get 1 after putting: " + cache.get(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition the `CacheManager` must be `close()` properly

Comment: You are right. I did through muscle memory in my example :-) Let me edit my answer

Comment: Where will be the folder be saved from here .with(persistence("cache"))  ??

Comment: what is the problem with org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Couldn't lock rootDir: